# Error in upgrading report server project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

I recently have attempted to migrate a solution created and developed in Visual Studio (VS) 2012 to VS 2017.

I've managed to migrate all projects of my solution except for a Report Server Project. When I try to open my solution in VS 2017 I get the following message:

[image]

I click on **Yes** and VS automatically upgrades the project file (this is a file having the extension `.rptproj`)

When I now try to build the project I get the following error message:

> Error     Copying file Reports\Report\Project1\MyReportProject.rptproj.user to
>   obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\Reports\Report
>   Project1\MyReportProject.rptproj.user failed. Could not find file
>   'Reports\Report Project1\MyReportProject.rptproj.user'

I thought the upgrade would be performed transparently. Am I missing something? Is there any extra step I should take in order to do the upgrade?

**Note:** I've already downloaded and installed the latest version of [Microsoft Reporting Services Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio) .vsix package.

Comment: I'd suggest contact MS on their forum or emailing  ssrs-feedback@service.microsoft.com as this would be something they would be interested in dealing with

Comment: update VS2017 to update 15.5 and look if it fixes the issue

Comment: 15.5 should be available to all editions.

Comment: Unfortunately upgrading from 15.4.4 to 15.5 did not solve the issue.

Comment: Exclude that file form your project

Comment: @ErikEJ This file is automatically generated and added to the project by Visual Studio. Therefore I don't know how to exclude it from the Report Services project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the latest msbuild.exe for SSRS is [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/09/25/msbuild-support-for-reporting-services-projects-now-available/).

This includes steps of up-gradation of SSRS for both VS15 and VS17.

Once you install the latest update, depending on which version of Visual Studio you’re using, the new files enabling MSBuild for your projects will be installed in different folder path:

In Visual Studio 2017, it’ll will be a nested folder in your Visual Studio folder hierarchy. For example, the location with the Community Edition is in the Community folder:

[image]

### Edit 1:

Try these steps:

1) Close Visual Studio - 17

2) Open VS-17 Installer

3) Try to install the SSDT workflow as:

[image]

Comment: I've already gone through the procedure of installing the Microsoft Reporting Services Projects package. Please check the note in the OP.

Comment: Your error is not about upgrade, its visual studio internal error to open SSRS.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I've already installed SQL Server Data Tools from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt#ssdt-for-visual-studio-2017) link.